# Setting NumberPicker default value

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I am making a number picker dialog having 2 number pickers, years and months. I want to show some default value in these 2 number picker, apart from 0, 0

[image]

Code::

```
    final NumberPicker numberPickerYear = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerYears);
    final NumberPicker numberPickerMonth = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMonths);

    numberPickerYear.setMaxValue(35);
    numberPickerYear.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerYear.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    numberPickerMonth.setMaxValue(11);
    numberPickerMonth.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerMonth.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: did you tried numberPickerYear.setValue(9);

Comment: at first search on google . old question

Answer (score 4):

**READ Carefully:**

void **setValue** (int value)
Set the current value for the number picker.

> 1. If the argument is less than the `getMinValue()` and `getWrapSelectorWheel()` is false the current value is set to the
>      `getMinValue()` value.
> 2. If the argument is less than the `getMinValue()` and `getWrapSelectorWheel()` is true the current value is set to the
>      `getMaxValue()` value.
> 3. If the argument is less than the `getMaxValue()` and `getWrapSelectorWheel()` is false the current value is set to the
>      `getMaxValue()` value.
> 4. If the argument is less than the `getMaxValue()` and `getWrapSelectorWheel()` is true the current value is set to the
>      `getMinValue()` value.

```
    final NumberPicker numberPickerYear = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerYears);
    final NumberPicker numberPickerMonth = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMonths);

    numberPickerYear.setMaxValue(35);
    numberPickerYear.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerYear.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPickerYear.setValue(17);// here to set default value of 

    numberPickerMonth.setMaxValue(11);
    numberPickerMonth.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerMonth.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPickerMonth.setValue(5);// here to set default value of numberPickerMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need find your Resource id and assign max and min value like this:

```
final NumberPicker numberPickerYear = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerYears);
final NumberPicker numberPickerMonth = (NumberPicker) expDialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMonths);

numberPickerYear.setMaxValue(35);
numberPickerYear.setMinValue(0);
numberPickerYear.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

numberPickerMonth.setMaxValue(11);
numberPickerMonth.setMinValue(0);
numberPickerMonth.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Then finally add two default values like this:

```
numberPickerYear.setValue(5);
numberPickerMonth.setValue(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance set the value using the

```
numberPickerYear.setValue(default_year);
numberPickerMonth.setValue(default_month);
```

more info at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html